# Парсинг сайта, вывод цены и названия. Python bs4, requests

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Я написал простую программу для парсинга, но проблема в том, что цена и название выводиться не так как надо.

```
★ Bowie Knife | Lore. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | karrigan | Cluj-Napoca 2015. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | floppy (Gold) | Antwerp 2022. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Falchion Knife | Lore. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
AWP | Oni Taiji. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  M9 Bayonet | Damascus Steel. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Gut Knife | Doppler Sapphire. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Skeleton Knife | Crimson Web. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | chrisJ | Cologne 2015. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | gob b | Cluj-Napoca 2015. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
SG 553 | Dragon Tech. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Butterfly Knife | Freehand. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
G3SG1 | Demeter. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | Virtus.Pro (Foil) | Cologne 2015. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Five-SeveN | Candy Apple. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | chopper (Gold) | Boston 2018. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Butterfly Knife | Bright Water. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Karambit | Crimson Web. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  Shadow Daggers | Lore. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Shadow Daggers | Lore. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  Falchion Knife | Lore. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | olofmeister (Gold) | Katowice 2019. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Flip Knife | Autotronic. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Stiletto Knife | Doppler Sapphire. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | Flipsid3 Tactics (Foil) | Boston 2018. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | hazed (Foil) | MLG Columbus 2016. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Karambit | Black Laminate. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
USP-S | Printstream. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  Talon Knife | Scorched. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Sport Gloves | Bronze Morph. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  Butterfly Knife | Freehand. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Souvenir M4A1-S | Master Piece. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
P90 | Run and Hide. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  Classic Knife | Slaughter. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Classic Knife. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Bayonet. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  Flip Knife | Gamma Doppler Phase 2. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Souvenir AWP | Desert Hydra. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ M9 Bayonet | Boreal Forest. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sticker | USTILO | Boston 2018. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
AK-47 | Red Laminate. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Classic Knife | Night Stripe. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  Falchion Knife | Doppler Phase 2. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Karambit | Urban Masked. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Butterfly Knife | Gamma Doppler. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Bayonet | Black Laminate. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
Sawed-Off | Kiss♥Love. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Moto Gloves | Boom!. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  Karambit | Urban Masked. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★  Bowie Knife | Doppler Sapphire. Цена: 245.36 рублей.
★ Bowie Knife | Lore. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | karrigan | Cluj-Napoca 2015. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | floppy (Gold) | Antwerp 2022. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Falchion Knife | Lore. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
AWP | Oni Taiji. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  M9 Bayonet | Damascus Steel. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Gut Knife | Doppler Sapphire. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Skeleton Knife | Crimson Web. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | chrisJ | Cologne 2015. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | gob b | Cluj-Napoca 2015. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
SG 553 | Dragon Tech. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Butterfly Knife | Freehand. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
G3SG1 | Demeter. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | Virtus.Pro (Foil) | Cologne 2015. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Five-SeveN | Candy Apple. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | chopper (Gold) | Boston 2018. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Butterfly Knife | Bright Water. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Karambit | Crimson Web. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  Shadow Daggers | Lore. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Shadow Daggers | Lore. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  Falchion Knife | Lore. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | olofmeister (Gold) | Katowice 2019. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Flip Knife | Autotronic. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Stiletto Knife | Doppler Sapphire. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | Flipsid3 Tactics (Foil) | Boston 2018. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | hazed (Foil) | MLG Columbus 2016. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Karambit | Black Laminate. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
USP-S | Printstream. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  Talon Knife | Scorched. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Sport Gloves | Bronze Morph. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  Butterfly Knife | Freehand. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Souvenir M4A1-S | Master Piece. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
P90 | Run and Hide. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  Classic Knife | Slaughter. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Classic Knife. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Bayonet. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  Flip Knife | Gamma Doppler Phase 2. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Souvenir AWP | Desert Hydra. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ M9 Bayonet | Boreal Forest. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sticker | USTILO | Boston 2018. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
AK-47 | Red Laminate. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Classic Knife | Night Stripe. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  Falchion Knife | Doppler Phase 2. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Karambit | Urban Masked. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Butterfly Knife | Gamma Doppler. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Bayonet | Black Laminate. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
Sawed-Off | Kiss♥Love. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Moto Gloves | Boom!. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  Karambit | Urban Masked. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★  Bowie Knife | Doppler Sapphire. Цена: 320.26 рублей.
★ Bowie Knife | Lore. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | karrigan | Cluj-Napoca 2015. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | floppy (Gold) | Antwerp 2022. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Falchion Knife | Lore. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
AWP | Oni Taiji. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★  M9 Bayonet | Damascus Steel. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Gut Knife | Doppler Sapphire. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Skeleton Knife | Crimson Web. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | chrisJ | Cologne 2015. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | gob b | Cluj-Napoca 2015. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
SG 553 | Dragon Tech. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Butterfly Knife | Freehand. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
G3SG1 | Demeter. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | Virtus.Pro (Foil) | Cologne 2015. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Five-SeveN | Candy Apple. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | chopper (Gold) | Boston 2018. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Butterfly Knife | Bright Water. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Karambit | Crimson Web. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★  Shadow Daggers | Lore. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Shadow Daggers | Lore. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★  Falchion Knife | Lore. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | olofmeister (Gold) | Katowice 2019. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Flip Knife | Autotronic. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Stiletto Knife | Doppler Sapphire. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | Flipsid3 Tactics (Foil) | Boston 2018. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | hazed (Foil) | MLG Columbus 2016. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Karambit | Black Laminate. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
USP-S | Printstream. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★  Talon Knife | Scorched. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Sport Gloves | Bronze Morph. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★  Butterfly Knife | Freehand. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Souvenir M4A1-S | Master Piece. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
P90 | Run and Hide. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★  Classic Knife | Slaughter. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Classic Knife. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Bayonet. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★  Flip Knife | Gamma Doppler Phase 2. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Souvenir AWP | Desert Hydra. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ M9 Bayonet | Boreal Forest. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sticker | USTILO | Boston 2018. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
AK-47 | Red Laminate. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Classic Knife | Night Stripe. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★  Falchion Knife | Doppler Phase 2. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Karambit | Urban Masked. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Butterfly Knife | Gamma Doppler. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Bayonet | Black Laminate. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
Sawed-Off | Kiss♥Love. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
★ Moto Gloves | Boom!. Цена: 2 302.56 рублей.
```

Я решил все названия и цены не указывать, так как их там минимум 2500.

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ('https://lis-skins.ru/market/csgo/?page=90')
request = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')

skins = soup.find_all("div", class_='name-inner')
prices = soup.find_all("div", class_="price")


for price in prices:
    for skin in skins:
        print(f'{skin.text}. Цена: {price.text} рублей.')
```

Заранее спасибо <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
for price, skin in zip(prices, skins):
    print(f'{skin.text}. Цена: {price.text} рублей.')
```

но лучше так:

```
items = soup.findAll('div', class_='item')
for item in items:
    skin = item.find(class_='name-inner')
    price = item.find(class_="price")
    print(f'{skin.text}. Цена: {price.text} рублей.')
```

Comment: Можете объяснить почему второй вариант лучше?

Comment: @Александр Ну может потому что более нагляднее. Парсим каждую карточку товара на наличее цены и названия, а не весь сайт на наличее цен и названий товара (как у автора топика)